# Visual Studio - How i can use a variable into a object name?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i'm learning Visual, and i'm tryind to do this:

```
    For Each folder In Dir.Subfolders
        list = list + 1
        C1CheckBox(list).Text = folder.Name
    Next
```

I have a lot of checkboxex named C1CheckBox1, C1CheckBox2, C1CheckBox3, etc... then i want to change the text of each checkbox by the folder name (using the list var to reference the object)...

How i can do this?

thankyou for read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find controls by name with [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

```
For Each folder In Dir.Subfolders
    list = list + 1
    Dim cb As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find("C1CheckBox" & list, True)(0)
    cb.Text = folder.Name
Next
```

This will search the entire form including its child containers. If you know all your checkboxes are in say, panel1, you could be more specific:

```
Dim cb As CheckBox = Me.Panel1.Controls.Find("C1CheckBox" & list, False)(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all of the checkboxes setting their text as you go. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559699/1428388)  for an example for how to enumerate the checkboxes